# How to get the a percentage column along with the value/ count column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Shown below are the details from a DataFrame

[image]

Below is the Syntax used to add a percentage column,

```
df1 = df[['Attrition', 'Gender',"JobSatisfaction"]]
df1 = df1.groupby(['Attrition','Gender'])['Job_Satisfaction'].value_counts().reset_index(name='count')
df1['%'] =   100 * df1['count']/  df1.groupby(['Attrition','Gender','Job_Satisfaction'])['count'].transform('sum')
df1 = df1 .sort_values(by=['Gender','Attrition','Job_Satisfaction'])
df1
```

below is the results I get

[image]

How can I add a percentage column shown below,
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can normalize using [`groupby.transform('sum')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and multiply by 100:

```
df['%'] = df['count'].div(df.groupby('Gender')['count'].transform('sum')).mul(100)
```

For a string:

```
df['%'] = (df['count']
           .div(df.groupby('Gender')['count'].transform('sum')
           .mul(100).astype(int).astype(str).add('%')
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

The percentage denominator you want is total Gender count, hence `df1.groupby(['Attrition','Gender','Job_Satisfaction'])` was incorrect.
Use `df1.groupby(['Gender'])` instead.